# AWS Elastic Beanstalk error while setting env var via .ebextentions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to set environment variables in AWS EB using .ebextentions as sited in https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-env-variables-shell/

My current config is:

```
commands:
  setvars:
    command: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r 'to_entries | .[] | "export \(.EB_ENV_NAME)=\"\(.r-service)\""' > /etc/profile.d/sh.local
```

While running the command to deploy the application to EB, I encounter the following error:

```
Command failed on instance. Return code: 3 Output: (TRUNCATED)...t <top-level>, line 1:
to_entries | .[] | "export \(.EB_ENV_NAME)=\"\(.r-service)\""
jq: error: b/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
to_entries | .[] | "export \(.EB_ENV_NAME)=\"\(.r-service)\""
jq: 3 compile errors.
command setvars in .ebextensions/00_setvars.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

Can someone please let me help this solve this error? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried testing the command locally?

Comment: @StefanN I did, but it did not work, I tried to deploy it from my local env.